# Embedding Vaadin app in IFrame

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, vaadin, xss

We are looking to integrate a nodejs app with our in house vaadin app.

- The suggested approach is to embed the vaadin app within an IFrame of the nodejs app;
- Provide a javascript proxy that captures node app events and forwards to the Vaadin app in an IFrame;
- The vaadin app is then free to communicate with it's server backend and post or retrieve any data required, which may then be proxied back to the nodejs app.

Other than the potential for CrossSite Scripting issues can you see any other pitfalls with this approach?

Comment: I'm curious: How do you proxy it back, i.e. pass data from vaadin app to node.js app?